What is the nvim way to move out of {} and () and "" without going to normal mode and using hl?
I am tired of going to normal mode and using h or l then i or a every time I have to move out from parenthesis or brackets or quotations (""), is there a better nvim way to do the same like pressing the tab key or something?
I tried setting some key bindings in auto-pairs.lua (nvim-autopairs plugin) but it didn't work,
I am pasting my auto-pairs.lua setup here:
return {
    "windwp/nvim-autopairs",
    event = { "InsertEnter" },
    dependencies = {
        "hrsh7th/nvim-cmp",
    },
    config = function()
        -- import nvim-autopairs
        local autopairs = require("nvim-autopairs")

        -- configure autopairs
        autopairs.setup({
            check_ts = true, -- enable treesitter
            ts_config = {
                lua = { "string" }, -- don't add pairs in lua string treesitter nodes
                javascript = { "template_string" }, -- don't add pairs in javscript template_string treesitter nodes
                java = false, -- don't check treesitter on java
            },
        })

        -- import nvim-autopairs completion functionality
        local cmp_autopairs = require("nvim-autopairs.completion.cmp")

        -- import nvim-cmp plugin (completions plugin)
        local cmp = require("cmp")

        -- make autopairs and completion work together
        cmp.event:on("confirm_done", cmp_autopairs.on_confirm_done())
    end,
}


You will find all the answers in :help navigation

If your cursor is anywhere inside the quotes, you could use Ctrl-o $
Ex:
"na|me"
Ctrl+o $
"name"| <-- your cursor goes to the end of the line

Help: Ctrl-o Executes 1 command and returns to insert mode.
Any navigation would work w, e, t, f, h, j, etc...

in addition to the above answer with Ctrl-o, you could also just type the closing parenthesis or brackets or quotation. Neovim then exits the bracket and remains in insert mode.
